# SMAC: (how) can I move all of my formers first?

Tags: alpha-centauri

I am in the late game, with lots of mind worm attacks, no matter how green I am.

Often, when military units ask for orders, I tell them to skip this turn. Inevitably, I later move a settler to discover alien life forms, but my military units have moved and cannot handle the situation.

Is there any configuration file tweak to cause the game to ask for orders for all formers first, then all military units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

Just make yourself a habit to <kbd>W</kbd> (wait) all military units until it starts cycling and then <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> End Turn (skip all) if no menace looming.

You may have nearby military units on Hold to activate and help.
**Good news:** *some* nearby units may have not *yet* skipped their move at the moment you see the menace. Find them by location Base (<kbd>F4</kbd>) or at Military Nexus (<kbd>F7</kbd>) and try salvage your civilian.
**Bad news:** they may have already skipped their move and this can not be reverted (shame on Sid Meier).

*Sorry for a short/unreferenced answer, but nothing more can be added here.*

Comment: Alas, that's exactly what I do, but I always play on a huge map and move all units by hand. I never have any military units on hold, in case I forget them, so it's a few hundred `W` and, even then, I can't be sure that I have cycled through all formers :-(